# How to get random 100 numbers in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, random, generator

This is the code that I used for this task:

```
import kotlin.random.Random

fun main(args:Array<String>) {

val randomnum = List(100) { Random.nextInt(0, 100)}
println(randomnum)

}
```

Can you help me get some other methods to get the same output as this code?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I think this is the already the best way!

Comment: Thank you @AnimeshSahu . One question if you don't mind. How do I printout numbers descending from  100 to 0 with this same method?
Thank you

Comment: I have this code
`val randomnum = List(100) { Random.nextInt(0, 100)}`
What do I need to change here so that my println output is
`[100,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92,91... etc till 0]`  @AnimeshSahu

Comment: Maybe more efficient `(100 downTo 0).toList()` it will generate list from 100 to 0 and you'll get desired result :)

Comment: Yes that's it! I am still learning how to logically think about coding, so I apologize for the inconvenience, and Thank you very much for your help :) @AnimeshSahu